# hide keyboard in android?

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I am new to android development.

I am creating an application in  which when app launches the edittextfield getfocus automatically and the keyboard pop-up.I want to hide the keyboard by default and show when edittextField get focus. I have tried this method but it's not working.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your manifest file:

pput it there:
(on your especific activity)

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"

Answer (score 1):

Declaring **android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"** in corresponding activity tag on Manifest file will solve this. But study about this attribute here.

[android:windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)